# Wait for element with Selenium - what is the different of using pollingEvery

Tags: scala, selenium

Consider this:

```
FluentWait fluentWait = new FluentWait[WebDriver](driver)
      .withTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .pollingEvery(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

fluentWait(120).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element))
```

What is the different of using `fluentWait` with `pollingEvery` and without `pollingEvery` ?
What does `pollingEvery` going ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Fluent wait, if we specify `pollingEvery`, driver will check the availability for a particular element, for every n (10 in this case) seconds (frequency) specified like `pollingEvery(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`. If we do not specify the same, by default it will check with the frequency of 500 milliseconds.

Hope this helps